# How to import a python module after downloading it from the same python program

Tags: python, pynput

What I am trying to do is that I have a simple python program which print the the key which I
pressed right now so for that I am doing is it thorough pynput module and if it is not available than download it from the internet. But when I download it I needed to restart the code to get worked properly.

HERE IS THE CODE:-

```
import os  

def download_it():
    try:
        os.system('pip3 install pynput') 
        from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
    except:
        download_it()   #this will rerun the code it there is not internet connection or some failure happen

try:
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
except:
    download_it()

def on_press(key):
    print(key)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Is there any way so that i need not to restart the code to get it worked.

Comment: So, you want to import right after download? If that is the case, have you tried importlib? [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in the [importlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) I believe.

Note that in [import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

> If you are dynamically importing a module that was created since the interpreter began execution (e.g., created a Python source file), you may need to call invalidate_caches() in order for the new module to be noticed by the import system.

Comment: Can you explain it little bit more.

Comment: It will be great with example